Apps Script doPost(e) not receiving JSON data from Box webhook
I have this simple code:
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}

Already deployed this as a web app, and copied the web app URL.
In Box, I created a Webhook app and then included the apps script web app URL as the address. However, when I trigger the webhook, my apps script doesn't log anything. It doesn't even show any failed execution.
I tried using a temporary url from webhook.site, and it is properly receiving JSON data from the Box webhook, so I figured the issue might be with apps script.
Other notes:

I'm using a corporate email address, and the web app url goes with something like this: https://script.google.com/a/macros/company.com/s/xxxx/exec where company.com is our domain. I tried changing this to https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx/exec but still doesn't work.

Where do you think did I go wrong with setting up the apps script web app? Thanks in advance!
Update:
Here is my deployment configuration. In the 'who has access', there's no 'Anyone' option, just 'Anyone within [Company name]'. Could that be the reason?

Also, here is my execution panel, though it's empty and the executions there are just me manually running the function and trying to figure out something.



Show your deployment configuration as written in tag info page. 2. Show your executions tab


Try using BetterLog instead of Logger.log().

@TheMaster I added the deployment config and executions tab, with some minor details. Thanks for the help!

Who has access should be "Anyone" - not "Anyone within company". If that option is unavailable, contact your admin to enable that option.

Thanks for this. I guess this indeed is the reason why. Unfortunately, our admin does not want to enable this due to security concerns. I tried using a personal gmail web app with who can access being 'Anyone' and run web app as 'Me', and somehow I'm getting some response. However, the execution keeps failing and I can't use try catch to identify the error. Any idea what could be the reason why?
Also, if I'm still to use our corporate email account, are there are alternatives to still do this? Thanks again!

@Jordzzz  It's failing, because you don't return anything from the function. As suggested by TheAddonDepot, you can try BetterLog for logging. Alternatively, you need a Google cloud project linked to this apps script project for default stackdriver logging to work. As to alternatives, I believe webapp deployment is one of the safest and efficient way to link(if you know what you're doing and take strict security precautions). Nevertheless, you can always poll Box api and get the data without the need to deploy a hook.

Thanks for the guidance. I'm actually learning as I go with this, as I'm not really a developer and just got interest due to our team's need. I'll try out BetterLog and look into Google cloud project, and see what I can do from there. Thanks again!

@Jordzzz if that helped, consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the  left of this post.
